# Issue associating ms-powerpoint protocol to powerpoint

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-powerpoint, file-association

When trying to open powerpoint through sharepoint or teams I get an error that no application is associated to the protocol (ms-powerpoint). This seems to be true when I check in windows setting but when I try to associate ppt it doesn't appear in my list of applications.

However I have office 2016 pro installed - the same version as on my other pc where it does work.

I've tried to figure out the progid to make the association manually in regristry but can't figure it out.

Comment: Try repairing Office:  Control Panel | Programs & Features | select Office then choose Change from the bar at the top of the list of programs. Try the Quick Repair first, then the full repair if that doesn't help. Another possible quick fix is to execute POWERPNT.EXE with the /REGSERVER command line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 1909 the following solution worked for me:
run: Start Menu -> Microsoft Office Tools -> Microsoft Office 2016 – Quick Repair
(it was not possible to find the repair tool in Programs & Features).

Comment: The repair tool comes when you select the program in Programs & Features and click on Modify.